# MariaDB: Access denied from remote acess, but supposedly have permissions

Tags: mysql, mariadb, remote-access

I just installed MariaDB on my machine, created a new user and granted all permissions to it.

Here is me connecting from localhost with the new account that should be able to connect from anywhere.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();
+--------------------+-----------------+
| USER()             | CURRENT_USER()  |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| USERNAME@localhost | USERNAME@%      |
+--------------------+-----------------+
```

And here is me, with the root account, checking all its permissions.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'USERNAME'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for USERNAME@%                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `USERNAME`.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Now, when I try to connect from anywhere else, it says I have no permission.

Here is from Vagrant

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant$ mysql --user=USERNAME --password=123456 --host=192.168.33.1 --port=3306
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'192.168.33.10' (using password: YES)
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant$ mysql --user=USERNAME --password=123456 --host=10.0.2.2 --port=3306
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'172.16.254.1' (using password: YES)
```

And even trying to set it up with DBeaver from host machine, it gives me the same `Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'172.16.254.1' (using password: YES)` error.
I'm not that understanding in Databases, but while trying to understand all my steps, this one bugged me out, as supposedly, '%' means anywhere in that situation.
I appreciate any help.

I think it need not be said, but I censored the username and passwords. Also, just in case, this username is not related to my system's username.

`Server version: 10.3.22-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 Ubuntu 19.10`

Comment: have you flushed the privileges too?

Comment: Flushed the privileges and even restarted the service.Considering that the setup was made yesterday and I'm resuming today after a refresh, "turning the machine off and on again" was also done.

Comment: For some reason it looks like wrong password or user (do you have access to error logs? maybe there you will see more)

Comment: If I run `mysql --user=USERNAME --password=123456` directly from host, from the command line, it works (It's how I got the `| USERNAME@localhost | USERNAME@% |`) part, so the username and password are not wrong. The problem seems to be related to the location.

Ironically, if I add the --host part, even from the host command line it won't work, and give me the same errors.

Comment: Can you show usernames and hosts for users you have in database? I think you might have the user user@location defined, and when you use ---host your host becomes other and not login in.

For example `CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '...';` is totally different user than `CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '....';` even if you connect from localhost and is shown differently.

Comment: I only have two users. ```SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
user, host / root, localhost / USERNAME, %``` I had a similar thought before, now that I look at it, maybe I should add the identified part to grant privileges?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out the problem was conflicted ports. Basically, although I was configuring everything properly, because there was already another service from docker (for another project) running mariadb (I believe unused to boot, since I never used it around here), everything was trying to access that rather than my host install.